# Qt6, QML: Нет горизонтальной полосы прокрутки при использовании ListView

Tags: qt, qml

Есть модель со списком путей к картинкам которые потом отображаются через `ListView`, но если ширина картинки больше окна, то горизонтальная полоса прокрутки не появляется.

---

UPD: Если у `ListView` вручную установить значение в свойствве `contentWidth`, то полоса прокрутки появляется. Не понятно почему это свойство никак не меняется при наличии элементов в `ListView`.

UPD2: Нашел в доке [следующее](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#flickable-direction), похоже что нужно в ручную вычислить максимальную ширину всех существующих элементов в `ListView` и установить её в `contentWidth`

---

```
Component {
    id: imageDelegate

    RowLayout {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

        Image {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            source: display
        }
    }
}

ScrollView {
    id: scrollView

    anchors.fill: parent

    ListView {
        id: listView

        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        boundsMovement: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        flickDeceleration: 100000
        model: stringListModel

        delegate: imageDelegate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема связана прежде всего с тем, что `ListView` *переиспользует* делегаты для экономии памяти, *либо уничтожает невидимые* в текущий момент. Таким образом, ширину всех делегатов в модели (если она не помещается в виджет) он знать не может, и по этой же причине вы не сможите её узнать. Поэтому при скроле у вас ширина будет скакать. Если у вас не тысячи элементов и *overhead* позволяет, то смело используйте связку `Flickable`+`ColumnLayout`+`ListModel`:

```
Flickable {
    contentWidth: layout.implicitWidth
    contentHeight: layout.implicitHeight
    contenmtItem: ColumnLayout {
        id: layout
        Repeater {
            model: ListModel { id: model }
            delegate: Item { }
        }
    }
}
```

Ещё удобнее будет сделать вспомогательный элемент и передавать в него `Item` снаружи через свойство:

```
property Item degelgateItem: null
```

Если вам нужно обязательно задавать ширину динамически, но при этом использовать `ListView` для экономичности, то просто создайте маппер:

```
property var mapper: new Map()

function setWidth(rowId,iWidth) {
    mapper.set(rowId,iWidth);
    let maxWidth = 0;
    for (const [id,width] of mapper)
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth,width);
    view.contentWidth = maxWidth;
}

Item {
    id: delegate
    Component.onCompleted: setWidth(rowId,implicitWidth)
    onImplicitWidthChanged: setWidth(rowId,implicitWidth)
}
```

Что при этом использовать в качестве `rowId` - решать вам. В любом случае, должно быть свойство, по которому можно определить уникальносить делегата без привязки к модели.

Comment: `ListView` мне как рах нужен из за того что он динамически создаёт и удаляет элементы. Пишут что `TableView` может показывать вертикальную и горизонтальную полосы прокрутки, завтра попробую его проверить.

Comment: @Bleser, я обновил ответ